# how to use tf operations in keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication, attributeerror

I am trying to us tensorflow operations within a keras model and I am quite confused about the mechanism and what Lambda layers do to tf tensors.

So this works:

```
a = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1, 2], dtype='float', name='a')
s= keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.transpose(tf.transpose(x)))(a)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=a, outputs=s)
```

but this does not work:

```
a = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1, 2], dtype='float', name='a')
s = tf.transpose(tf.transpose(a))
s = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)(s)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=a, outputs=s)
```

and it says:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

so is it always necessary to pack up tf operations within a layer?

Question 2 (was why I came up the previous one): do we have to pack with a custom layer to do matrix multiplication in keras?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Question 1: Yes, it is necessary to wrap tf operations with a layer, because keras models require certain functions/variables that aren't included with tensorflow ops. In this case, `_keras_history` is a property that is only produced by wrapping the op with a layer.

Question 2: Is the matrix multiplication traHave you considered using a keras `Dense` layer, with `use_bias=False`? If you want to use a constant for the weight vector, you could set the `kernel_initializer={constant}`, and `trainable=False`.

Comment: It seems that I have no problem running the second piece of code in OP, is it because I use tensorflow 2?