# Use tensorflow operation in tf.keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a pre-trained model, adding some new layers and operation and perform a training session in `tensorflow`. Therefore, I stumpled upon the `tf.keras.applications.*` namespace and started to use some of the implemented models there.

After loading the base model, I am adding these new layers like this:

```python
x = base_model.output
# this line seems to cause my error
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1]) 
# using this line solves the issue
# tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x) #
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax")(x)
```

When I now create a new `tf.keras.models.Model(...)` from the Tensor `x`, I get this error message:

```python
Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer`
(thus holding past layer metadata).
Found: Tensor("dense_27/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
```

This exception is caused because of using a `tf.*` operation inside the `tf.keras` model, I guess. In this situation I could easily use the keras alterantive instead, but now I have started wondering if there exists a workaround to use tensor operations inside the keras model anyhow. Or am I completely restricted to use `tf.keras.layer.*` operations?

Comment: You need to wrap your operations in a lambda layer, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860237/how-to-use-tf-operations-in-keras-models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As have been mentioned in the comment, you need to wrap TF operations in a `Lambda` layer (or any self-defined layer) so that Keras can find the required metadata for building the `Model` object.

```py
x = base_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1]))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax")(x)
```

It's probably worth noting that when trying to save and load this model, there would be an error complaining that the name `tf` is not defined.

```py
model = tf.keras.Model(base_model.input, x)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.save('1.h5')
m = tf.keras.models.load_model('1.h5')

# NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

It's because during model loading, `tf` is not imported in the scope where the `Lambda` layer is re-constructed. It can be solved via providing a `custom_objects` dictionary to `load_model`.

```py
m = tf.keras.models.load_model('1.h5', custom_objects={'tf': tf})
```